# Domain resolving slow on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

Ive been playing aroudn with the twitter API in a webserver and in my local machine. Ive noticed that in my local machine it works MUCH slowlier, so I think I have some DNS problems. Doint this commands gave me:

```
time echo "" | nc google.com 80
```

time: 20 seconds

```
time echo "" | nc 173.194.65.103 80
```

time: Instantly

Im running Ubuntu 11.10. Do you guys know how could I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Pedantic comment: DNS is not the same as resolving. They are two different functions. You had a resolver problem, not a DNS problem.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Comment: Note me that downvoted it but your analysis of the problem is incomplete.

Comment: What do you mean with "incomplete"? What do you thing is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing in /etc/resolv.conf

this lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

This is openDNS. Apparently my router DNS sucks. Thanks!

Comment: You can use https://code.google.com/p/namebench/ to check out which are the fastest DNS servers for your location.

Comment: I never use my home router's DNS for this reason - I usually set them as Google's Anycast DNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) or Level3's Anycast DNS (4.2.2.2 or 4.2.2.1 to 6).

Comment: It's HIGHLY unlikely that your router is doing anything other than using the DNS providers supplied to it by DHCP - i.e. it's more likely the fault of your service provider. Either that or you've misconfigured the router.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `dig` to debug the DNS output. It will give you the response time of your nameserver:

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7643
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     211 IN  A   209.85.147.147
google.com.     211 IN  A   209.85.147.99
google.com.     211 IN  A   209.85.147.103
google.com.     211 IN  A   209.85.147.104
google.com.     211 IN  A   209.85.147.105
google.com.     211 IN  A   209.85.147.106

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
;; WHEN: Sat Dec 10 17:01:05 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```